# why text is texted wrongly in this method in android?

Tags: android, textview, settext

please help me! at first please follow this algorithm:

1- `btn_set1` is clicked, its functions are doing.

2- `btn_set2` is clicked, "text1" is SetText ed into "+"!!!

WHY???
please help me, how can i solve this problem? thanks.

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        //time picker pannel
        case R.id.btn_set1:
            text1.setText(aTime);
            intent1 = new Intent(this, alarmService.class);
            intent1.putExtra("rq1", req_code);
            intent1.putExtra("alarm_time", alarm_time1);
            startService(intent1);
            alinear.setAnimation(animLeft);
            Linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.btn_set2:
            text2.setText(aTime);
            intent2 = new Intent(this, alarmService.class);
            intent2.putExtra("rq2", req_code);
            intent2.putExtra("alarm_time", alarm_time1);
            startService(intent2);
            LLinear.setAnimation(animLeft);
            Linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        case R.id.btn_cancle1:
            Linear.setAnimation(animLeft);
            Linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cancel_one(text1);
            break;

        case R.id.btn_cancle2:
            Linear.setAnimation(animLeft);
            Linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cancel_one(text2);
            break;
    }
}
private void cancel_one(TextView textView) {
    if(intent1 != null)
        stopService(intent1);

    if(intent2 != null)
        stopService(intent2);

    textView.setText("+");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to put a `break` statement in the `case 2:` and hence `case 3:` also gets invoked called when `case 2` is invoked